# In JavaScript is script guarantied to run after previous scripts in a document finished to run

Tags: javascript, execution

Please consider the following snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="script_1.js"></script>
    <script src="script_2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        //script_3
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can a one be sure that `script_3` is run only after `script_1` and `script_2` finished to execute and `script_2`c is run only after `script_1` finished, provided that there are no async code  in `script_1` and `script_2`?

Because now I have a situation, where `script_3` from time to time starts before `script_2` finished and it seems that all of the scripts don't have any async code. But I cannot reproduce this situation in a simpler example.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, as the code stands with no `defer` or anything else, the scripts are guaranteed to run in sequential order, in all browsers.

Comment: How exactly do the *seem* to have no async code? It would be nice if you could post their contents, even if you couldn't reduce the example code.

Comment: @Bergi , I can't post the code here. First reason is that it is rather big, the second is that I'm not allowed to disclose this code. Now, after the answer, I think that these files have some async code, I just did not spot it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a one be sure that script_3 is run only after script_1 and script_2 finished to execute and script_2c is run only after script_1 finished, provided that there are no async code in script_1 and script_2?

Yes, provided that none of the script tags uses the [`async` or `defer` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async).

Note that this is very different from this, however:

```
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script3.js"></script>
```

...where `script1.js` contains this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "script2.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode.appendChild(script);
```

...in which case the order of `script2.js` vs. `script3.js` is chaotic.

However, if `script1.js` used `document.write` to output the `script2.js` script tag, that would be like the markup version, and the order would be assured (1, then 2, then 3).